# Nested (parent/chield) Form request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request

I'm creating an api with laravel. I have created ProductRequest and ProductPriceRequest classes for request validation and they are working as expected.

A Product can have multiple ProductPrice.

Right now in order to create ProductPrice, I need to first create a Product and then create the ProductPrice associated with the Product.

```
//Create product
POST->http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products
{
 "name":"product1"
}
//Create productprice associated with product
Post->http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/69081258758830188/productprices
{
 "name":"productprice1"
}
```

But I would like to enable the creation of ProductPrice when the Product is created.

```
//Create product+productprice
POST->http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products
{
 "name": "prod2",
 "productPrices": [
  {
   "name": "pp1"
  },
  {
   "name": "pp2"
  }
 ]
}
```

Since I already have (and need) a ProductPriceRequest, how can I use ProductPriceRequest class inside ProductRequest to validate ProductPrice, if the request have a ProductPrice present.

I'm new to laravel (I'm using version 10) and php, and didn't find any examples of this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't try to reuse the same rules in another ProductPriceRequest class, in the ProductRequest I would just do something like

```
'prices.*.name' => ['required', 'min:3'],
'prices.*.id' => ['numeric'],
```

or whatever your rules are.

Technically, if you do want to use the same rules, you can put those repeating rules in the `ProductPrice` model and then use them in both FormRequest files, but I'm not sure if there wouldn't be any other collisions because here, the data is in array, but in another case (you haven't shown where else you use and need ProductPriceRequest), it may be another structure passed for the validation.

Comment: So your suggestion is to duplicate the validation rules? In the question, I'm showing the implemented workflow I have right now where ProductPriceRequest is used to validate a new productprice for a existing product.

Comment: Yes, I don't see such duplication as a very bad thing.